# accessing iOS device SSL certificate

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ssl, certificate

We are developing an iPhone app, and we have one client who wants to use their own SSL certificate bundle. As far as I know this is not possible since the app can't access the device cert (assuming the client just install their own bundles on each of their device). Other option is to submit a whole different app just for them, but that's not a good solution and I am trying to avoid that.

Does anyone have experience with this sorts of problems? I tried to google around but could not find anything.

Any help or direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is asking the client to manually install their certificate not an option - as described e.g. for [Charles Proxy untrusted certificate installing](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/ssl-connections-from-within-iphone-applications/).

Comment: is it, but then they will still have our bundle which is there anyway...they want only theirs to be there.

Comment: @TommyG I am also suffering with same kind of problem...If you have found any solution, please do let me know.....Thanx in advance..:)